# can i take user input to set color of my object in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

```js
// Load in the mesh and add it to the scene.
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( "models/cubic.js", function(geometry){
  // var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0x55B663});
  alert(geometry.faces.length);
  //for ( var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i ++ ) {

  var face = geometry.faces[ 2];
  face.color.setHex(0x55B663 );
  var face = geometry.faces[ 3 ];
  face.color.setHex(0x55B663 );
  var face = geometry.faces[ 4];
  face.color.setHex(0xFFFF00 );
  var face = geometry.faces[ 5 ];
  face.color.setHex(0xFFFF00 );
  var face = geometry.faces[ 8];
  face.color.setHex(0x666600 );
  var face = geometry.faces[ 9 ];
  face.color.setHex(0x666600 );
  var face = geometry.faces[ 6];
  face.color.setHex(0x1A1A00 );
  var face = geometry.faces[ 7 ];
  face.color.setHex(0x1A1A00 );
  var face = geometry.faces[ 10];
  face.color.setHex(0x00001a);
  var face = geometry.faces[ 11 ];
  face.color.setHex(0x00001a);
  var face = geometry.faces[ 1];
  face.color.setHex(0x200614);
  var face = geometry.faces[ 0 ];
  face.color.setHex(0x200614);

  //}
  mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors } ));
  //mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh1);
  mesh1.position.x=-3;
});
```

```html
<input id="color" type="text" />
<button id="submit" type="submit">submit</button>
```

can i take input from user to set color of what the users wants to set color for the object?

at above i have hard coded the colors for every faces of my object but i want to take input from user to set the colors.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can either set the color for the whole object via `mesh1.material.color` or you can alter the `mesh1.geometry.faces[...].color` values at any time. You may need to manage updates closely, check out https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates for hints on when you will need to theel THREE.js "something has changed"